# Identifying parents of Gustaf Tenglund born 1840 in Sweden?

Tags: birth-records, sweden

Gustaf Tenglund is my great Grandfather. I have drawn a complete blank on finding his parents. They just do not show up any where. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

As discovered by @JanMurphy the FamilySearch link to Gustaf is  http://familysearch.org/tree/#view=ancestor&person=LVYH-KGF, and there it is recorded in a shared tree that he was:

- born 6 Jun 1840 at Lundby, Västra Götaland, Sweden
- died 14 Apr 1918 Gudhem, Västra Götaland, Sweden

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take our [Tour]. I will remove your signature from your question because every post you make here is already signed by your user card. Would you be able to [edit] your question to explain the KVYH-KGF abbreviation that you have used and to tell us the country that you expect to find this birth record in, please?

Comment: KVYH-KGF has the format of a FamilySearch FamilyTree Person Number - however this ID (on that site) is Elizabeth Hall, not Gustaf Tenglund.

Comment: There is far too little information in the question as written for us to be able to help.  Can you please expand it a little.

Comment: The FamilyTree ID has a typo in it. I don't have time to edit the question but this might be the individual who is meant.  https://familysearch.org/tree/#view=ancestor&person=LVYH-KGF.  Gerald, I would also like to welcome you to G&FH.SE.  We ask that our community members add information about what they have already tried, and to put information relevant to the question in the question itself, so the rest of the community will be free to work on an answer.  Adding links to shared trees is not always helpful because the information you want to show us may not be there later.

Comment: Do you know what the source of the birth date and location for Gustaf is?  If not, do you know what the source of the death date and location for Gustaf is?  If not, what other record(s) do you have for Gustaf?

Answer (score 1):

The mother to Gustaf Tenglund is: Anna Andersdotter *20/12 1814 in Broddetorp, C:3 page 263.

She died in Norra-Lundby, Varnhem 07/02 1848 C:3 page 257, sid 45.

Comment: Hi Lars, welcome to the site. What's your source and evidence for this information? You can add details using the [edit] button below your post.